# Is there any way to fix my main class for my adjacency list graph?

Tags: java

So basically I'm suppose to take the numbers from a file Ex.

[image: File]

And turn it into this Ex.

[image: Result]

We're suppose to make a graph class and store a adjacency list representation of a graph. We're also suppose to do it with an array of arraylists. So I got some help making the graph class and I'm making it so that the users file is processed through the graph class but for some reason there's an error and the output isn't right. Can someone help with this?

**Graph Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Graph {
ArrayList<Integer> [] nodes;
int n_nodes;

public Graph(int numberNodes){
    this.nodes = new ArrayList[numberNodes+1];
    this.n_nodes = numberNodes;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_nodes + 1; i++){
        nodes[i] = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}


public void addNeighbor(int node, int neighbor){
    nodes[node].add(neighbor);
}

public String toString(){
    StringBuilder myGraph = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++){
        myGraph.append(i);
        ArrayList<Integer> neighbors = nodes[i];
        int totalNeighbors = neighbors.size();
        for(int j = 0; j < totalNeighbors; j++){
            int myneighbor = neighbors.get(j);
            myGraph.append(" -> " + myneighbor);
        }
        myGraph.append('\n');
    }
    return myGraph.toString();
   }}
```

**Main Class**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Program1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = null;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    Scanner ans = new Scanner(System.in);

        int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No File Selected");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int y = input.nextInt();
    int x = 0;
    Graph graph = new Graph(y);
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            x = input.nextInt();
            graph.addNeighbor(i, x);
        }
        System.out.println(graph.toString());
    }
    }}
```

Also I'm new to the whole stackoverflow website so sorry if my wording isn't clear or my code isn't formatted good enough.

**Edit**

This is the error it's showing
[image: Error]

Comment: try also using `input.hasNextInt ()`

Comment: I tried that already it was the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As `3` as read by

```
int y = input.nextInt();
```

is on a different line then you need to read the `CR-LF` as well.

Personally I would use the following paradigm

```
str = input.nextLine () 
// convert to int
while (input.hasNextLine) {
    str = input.nextLine () 
    arr[] = str.split (" ");
    // loop through length of arr - in your code `y` is not updated
        add arr[x] to graph
```

so basically you want something like

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    String line = input.nextLine();
    int y = 0;
    if (line != null) {
        y = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());  
    }

    Graph graph = new Graph(y);
    while (input.hasNextLine() && y > 0) {
        if (input.hasNextLine()) {
            line = input.nextLine();
        }
        String nums[] = line.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

            int x = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);  
            graph.addNeighbor(i, x);
        }
        System.out.println(graph.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I'm confused and don't really understand where you're going with this. Where would you want me to implement that code?